# Dowsing chart book with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I works between science and geobiology in France and I would like to create custom dowsing charts which would looks like this exemple :

[image]

Or

[image]

Actually I am not really skilled in programming and I am a simple user of latex, so i might need help to start with this.
Maybe  anyone have in mind some clues / exemples to look on to get this working with TikZ.

In my mind I would like to enter a list of terms, and that the TikZ script automatic  split into angle angle sections with automation.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you add a freehand drawing of what you ultimately want to achieve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome! It is not too difficult to draw something like that. One way to do that is to define a pic and repeat it over and over. What is, however, a bit cumbersome is to punch in texts from a screen shot. So I replaced some of them by generic texts.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,decorations.text,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,node distance=1ex,
    pics/pilz/.style={code={
     \tikzset{pilz/.cd,#1}
     \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pilz/##1}}%   
     \draw[pic actions] (\pv{alpha}+\pv{beta}/2:\pv{r}) -- (\pv{alpha}+\pv{beta}/2:\pv{R}) 
      foreach \XX in {1,...,\pv{n}} 
      {to[out=0,in=-120] 
        ({{\pv{alpha}+\pv{beta}/2-\XX*\pv{beta}/\pv{n}+\pv{beta}/(2*\pv{n})}}:\pv{xi}*\pv{R})
      to[out=-60,in=180] 
        ({\pv{alpha}+\pv{beta}/2-\XX*\pv{beta}/\pv{n}}:\pv{R})}
      -- (\pv{alpha}-\pv{beta}/2:\pv{r});   
      \path[decorate,decoration={text along path, text=\pv{text},text align=center}]
      (\pv{alpha}+\pv{beta}/2:\pv{r}/2+\pv{R}/2) 
      arc[start angle=\pv{alpha}+\pv{beta}/2,end angle=\pv{alpha}-\pv{beta}/2,
       radius=\pv{r}/2+\pv{R}/2];
    }},pilz/.cd,r/.initial=1,R/.initial=2,alpha/.initial=90,
    beta/.initial=45,xi/.initial=1.1,text/.initial={},n/.initial=1]
 \path foreach \Y [count=\X] in {fox,marmot,cat,koala,bear,duck,mouse,%
 anteater,rhino,hippo,lion,tiger,lynx,owl}  
  {pic[rotate={90+180/28-180*\X/14}]{pilz={beta=180/14,r=5,R=6.5,text=|\sffamily|\Y}}
  };
 \foreach \X in {-10,...,10} 
 {\pic[rotate={-180*\X/21},fill=gray!25]{pilz={beta=180/21,r=4,R=5,xi=1.05}};
  \path   (90-180*\X/21:4.7)node{$\mathsf{\X}$};
 }
 \path foreach \Y [count=\X] in {mental,spiritual,overall,physical,eotional}    
  {pic[rotate={90+180/10-180*\X/5},fill=white]{pilz={beta=180/5,n=3,r=3,R=4,xi=1.05,
    text=|\sffamily|\Y}}
  };
 \path foreach \Y [count=\X] in {astral,etheric,celestial,karmic,univeral}  
  {pic[rotate={90+180/10-180*\X/5},fill=gray!25]{pilz={beta=180/5,n=3,r=2,R=3,xi=1.05,
    text=|\sffamily|\Y}}
  };
 \path foreach \Y [count=\X] in {critical,poor,fair,good,excellent} 
  {pic[rotate={90+180/10-180*\X/5},fill=white]{pilz={beta=180/5,n=3,r=1,R=2,xi=1.05,
    text=|\sffamily\tiny|\Y}}
  };
 \draw foreach \X in {0,...,5} 
 {(\X*180/5:0.5) --(\X*180/5:1.5)};
 \draw[fill] (0.5,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=0.5];
 \path (0,0) node[below=1ex] (L){level of health}
  node[below=of L] (B){bodies}
  node[below=of B] (P){percentage of health}
  node[below=of P] (O){organs of the body};
 \foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in {L/1.25,B/2.5,B/3.5,P/4.5,O/5.75} 
 {\draw[thick,-{Latex[bend,length=2mm]}] (\X) -- (\Y-0.1*\Z,0|-\X) to[bend right=15] (\Y,0);
 \draw[thick,-{Latex[bend,length=2mm]}] (\X) -- (-\Y+0.1*\Z,0|-\X) to[bend left=15] (-\Y,0);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How awesome !
So nice !

Comment: Very fine work ! pic is very useful !!

Comment: @AlainMatthes You should tell this to David. He will tell you that `picture mode` is even better. ;-)

Comment: Ok, i posted a new question ;) Thanks again !